# Error creating array type custom message for ros service in python

Tags: ros, python, custom-message, rosservice, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I m trying to create a script that sends a service message to the server. Everything is good on the server side but I'm trying to build the client side using Python, just to get familiar with Python. However, with my limited knowledge of Python, building complex msgs is proving rather difficult.

I have HighLevelGoals.srv under nuric_sytem which is an array of HighLevelGoal.msg.

**HighLevelGoals.srv**

*HighLevelGoal[] goals

bool result*

---

**HighLevelGoal.msg**

*geometry_msgs/PoseStamped goal_pose*

*string goal_source*

---

My basic code is:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('nuric_system')

import sys
import rospy

from nuric_system.srv import HighLevelGoals
from nuric_system.msg import HighLevelGoal


def send_goal():
    rospy.wait_for_service('send_goals')
    
    send_goal_proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy('send_goals', HighLevelGoals)

    srv_goals=HighLevelGoals()
    goal_1=HighLevelGoal()
        
    goal_1.goal_source = "goal_sender"  
    goal_1.goal_pose.header.frame_id = "/sender"
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.position.x =-5.17850098489
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.position.y =-3.45
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.position.z =0.0
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.orientation.x= 0.0
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.orientation.y= 0.0
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.orientation.z= 0.192
    goal_1.goal_pose.pose.orientation.w=1.0

    
    srv_goals.goals.append(goal_1)
    resp1 = send_goal_proxy(srv_goals)

    return 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   send_goal()
   print("goal sent")
```

---

when I run it, I get the following error :

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_goal.py", line 40, in <module>
    send_goal()
  File "test_goal.py", line 33, in send_goal
    srv_goals.goals.append(goal_1)
AttributeError: 'HighLevelGoals' object has no attribute 'goals'**
```

---

But HighLevelGoals.srv does have a goals array which should be the same as goal_1 type. Clearly, Im not creating the message correctly. If anyone has any link for appropriate filling of msg arrays, please let me know.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125801/error-creating-array-type-custom-message-for-ros-service-in-python/) by [Vijeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11606/vijeth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using the wrong type. The service type is HighLevelGoals, but your goal is of type HighLevelGoalsRequest (and the response type will be HighLevelGoalsResponse). However, the service proxy will actually create the request from your parameters to it, thus the call would be:

```
send_goal_proxy(goals)
```

Where goals is of type list(HighLevelGoal). See http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services for more details

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vijeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11606/vijeth/) on 2014-02-07**:
Thank you so much Mike. That fixed it. Just to let others know,
I added goals=nuric_system.srv.HighLevelGoalsRequest()
which gave me NameError: global name 'nuric_system' is not defined
Then I changed from nuric_system.srv import HighLevelGoals to from nuric_system.srv import *
And that was it!!